# Edit by op makes question meaningless

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

I recently came across this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976159/show-that-if-p-adic-numbers). At first glance it just seems to be nonsense, but then I realized that it actually had had genuine mathematical content before the op edited it. In the comments to an answer they write "Can you delete your answer please? Because I want to use the concept to somewhere else confidential. Please understand me".

Beyond the issue of this specific question I wonder if there is some kind of community consensus on the appropriate reaction in such a case?

Should one just downvote the question for its low quality? Should one revert the op's edits? Or flag for moderator attention?

Comment: The consensus, I believe, is that such behavior (shown by the OP) is not at all appropriate. One can indeed revert the op's edits; if they continue to try to render their post meaningless, then flag for moderators' attention, for sure.